# Jest Unexpected identifier - Angular

Tags: angular, jestjs

I'm working on a jhipster generated angular project and when i try to run my tests im getting the following error

```
...
{import _ from 'lodash';                                                                                             
  SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
  at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript 
(node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js
...
```

I'm very new to jest and related configurations needed.  For what i can tell, jest is unable to deal with ES6 module system.

My jest.config.ts

```
module.exports = {
preset: 'jest-preset-angular',
setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/src/test/javascript/jest.ts'],
coverageDirectory: '<rootDir>/target/test-results/',
globals: {
    'ts-jest': {
        stringifyContentPathRegex: '\\.html$',
        tsConfig: '<rootDir>/tsconfig.json',
        astTransformers: [require.resolve('jest-preset-angular/InlineHtmlStripStylesTransformer')]
    }
},
coveragePathIgnorePatterns: [
    '<rootDir>/src/test/javascript'
],
moduleNameMapper: {
    'app/(.*)': '<rootDir>/src/main/webapp/app/$1'
},
reporters: [
    'default',
    [ 'jest-junit', { outputDirectory: './target/test-results/', outputName: 'TESTS-results- 
jest.xml' } ]
],
testResultsProcessor: 'jest-sonar-reporter',
transformIgnorePatterns: ['node_modules/(?!@angular/common/locales)'],
testMatch: ['<rootDir>/src/test/javascript/spec/**/@(*.)@(spec.ts)'],
rootDir: '../../../',
testURL: "http://localhost/"
};
```

I have already read about this problem but i unable to use the information i read to solve my own problem, so i kindly ask your help to shed some light on this for me please

Answer (score 1):

For those facing the similar problems.

After digging up on documentation and related posts i was able to figure out the solution.

Jest only understands CommonJS, by default Jest dosent transform any module inside node modules. So we need explicit inform Jest to look up and transform any module inside node module that ends up not beeing in commonJS.

In my case i just modified this line

```
transformIgnorePatterns: ['node_modules/(?!@angular/common/locales|problematic_module_name)']
```